# "Nose" is to "nasal" as "ear" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, analogy

If the adjective relating to the nose is *nasal* then what is the adjective relating to the ear?

I don't think it's "aural". I think it begins with *ot*-.

Comment: Easel _sounds_ right -  "Nose is to nasal, as ear is to easel" - but means a painters support.

Comment: At the risk of muddying the waters even more on this one, let's not forget [rhinal and rhinarial](http://wordquests.info/cgi/ice2-for.cgi?file=/hsphere/local/home/scribejo/wordquests.info/htm/L-Gk-rhino-pt1.htm&HIGHLIGHT=rhino). I'm sure millions of people would get those just because of [Tom's Rhinoplasty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom's_Rhinoplasty) on South Park.

Answer (score 24):

I suppose the word you are looking for specifically, is ["otic":](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/otic)

> of, relating/pertaining to, or located near the ear

One could therefore say: "Nose" is to "nasal", as "ear" is to "otic."

---

Additionally, although "aural" is commonly associated with "sound",  "aural" can also be used to refer to [pertaining to the ear:](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aural#English)

> of or pertaining to the ear.

This can be compared to ["nasal":](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal)

> Of or pertaining to the nose.

One could therefore also say: "Nose" is to "nasal", as "ear" is to "aural"

Comment: Nose:nasal:olfactory, Ear:otic:aural. It depends on whether you're talking about the sense organ itself, or the type of stimulus it responds to.

Comment: +1 *otic* is correct. If you have seasonal allergies, you get a *nasal* spray. If you get "Swimmer's ear," you can go to the pharmacy and get *otic* drops.

Comment: Just with the proviso that "otic" is quite a rare word. One other word that you can often use in compounds to mean "pertaining to the ear" is... "ear".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That is strange. Going by the Latin, these words should have the following meanings: nasal = of the nose; olfactory = smelling; otic = of the ear (from Greek *ous*, "ear"); aural = of the ear (slightly malformed, from Latin *auris*, "ear"). I'd say olfactory ~ auditory/auditive.

Comment: @Neil Coffey: "Otic" may be quite a rare word for you, but I've had an apparently incurable ear infection for a couple of decades now, so I personally am uncomfortably familiar with it. Also, note that if nothing else, the phonetics of *aural/oral* would discourage use of the former in a medical context.

Comment: @Cerberus: You're probably right in that if these words *had* evolved along the "most obvious" lines, the word OP seeks probably would have been *aural*. Time and chance, and all that. But on reflection now I don't think it's even that good for the triplet I posted, because it's an exceptionally vague word anyway (it's used of sound, ears, *and* auras, as well as being - ironically - misheard for/against *oral*). A better choice would probably have been **Ear:otic:auditory**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Great! I vote for your new trio. At least the difference between those three is audible.

Comment: @Cerberus: Together, we shall rule the world! Actually, I've always disliked *aural* - partly because of the particularly awkward scope for confusion with its homonym, but also because I tend to get irritated by anything to do with the mumbo-jumbo *body auru* context where it turns up. So I feel we're striking a blow against one of my lexical bugbears here. :)

Comment: @Fumble: I agree on both accounts! Especially the on-going battle against the evils of vague spiritualism strike a chord.  To clarity! And rationalism! I'm slightly tipsy now, but you may keep me to it in the morning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers How ... *earotic*.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest using "auricular":

> Of, relating to, or using the ear or the sense of hearing.

Like "nasal", which is derived from Latin "nasus" (nose), "auricular" is  also derived from Latin "auricula" (ear). However, "otic" has a Greek root.

Comment: *Auricular* is often used in biological/medical contexts, and might well be preferred for "everyday" use on the grounds that it's likely to be understood by more people than will know *otic*. If only because they can extend from the less-than-ideal *aural*, which they might know purely because they've learned to watch out for that one in case of confusion with *oral*.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context, "auditory" might be the right word. For example "auditory canal" would be analogous to "nasal passages".

Answer (score 0):

*[Auditory](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/auditory)* is your word.

> *au·di·to·ry/ˈôdiˌtôrē/*
>
> **Adjective**
>   *Of or relating to the sense of hearing: "the auditory nerves".*